# How to parallelize all the tests in an xunit collection fixture

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

### The Problem

I have a collection fixture in xunit test that lets me group all my tests together to allow for 1) a docker db setup and 2) each test to have their own service collection for activities.

The problem is that the since the tests are all in a collection fixture, the tests classes don't run in parallel. I've tried a few different things in their [parallelization docs](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html) with no luck. They still run pretty fast but it seems like this would be a big bump in perf that should be doable. Any thoughts here?

### The Code

i have a test collection fixture like this

```cs
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(TestFixture))]
public class TestFixtureCollection : ICollectionFixture<TestFixture> {}

public class TestFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    public static IServiceScopeFactory BaseScopeFactory;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
          // docker db setup

        builder.ConfigureServices();
        var services = builder.Services;

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        BaseScopeFactory = provider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    }

    
    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public static class ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection ReplaceServiceWithSingletonMock<TService>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TService : class
    {
        services.RemoveAll(typeof(TService));
        services.AddScoped<TService>(_ => Mock.Of<TService>());
        return services;
    }
}
```

testing service scope

```cs
public class TestingServiceScope 
{
    private readonly IServiceScope _scope;

    public TestingServiceScope()
    {
        _scope = BaseScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    }

    public TScopedService GetService<TScopedService>()
    {
        var service = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TScopedService>();
        return service;
    }

    public async Task<T> ExecuteScopeAsync<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, Task<T>> action)
        => await action(_scope.ServiceProvider);

    public Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<CoreDomainDbContext, Task<T>> action)
        => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<CoreDomainDbContext>()));
    
    public Task<int> InsertAsync<T>(params T[] entities) where T : class
    {
        return ExecuteDbContextAsync(db =>
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            }
            return db.SaveChangesAsync();
        });
    }
}
```

example test:

```cs
[Collection(nameof(TestFixture))]
public class AddRecipeCommandTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task can_add_new_recipe_to_db()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testingServiceScope = new TestingServiceScope();
        var fakeRecipeOne = new FakeRecipeForCreationDto().Generate();

        // Act
        var command = new AddRecipe.Command(fakeRecipeOne);
        var recipeReturned = await testingServiceScope.SendAsync(command);
        var recipeCreated = await testingServiceScope.ExecuteDbContextAsync(db => db.Recipes
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == recipeReturned.Id));

        // Assert
        recipeReturned.Title.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Title);
        recipeReturned.Visibility.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Visibility);
        recipeReturned.Directions.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Directions);
        recipeReturned.Rating.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Rating);
        recipeReturned.DateOfOrigin.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.DateOfOrigin);
        recipeReturned.HaveMadeItMyself.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.HaveMadeItMyself);

        recipeCreated.Title.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Title);
        recipeCreated.Visibility.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Visibility);
        recipeCreated.Directions.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Directions);
        recipeCreated.Rating.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.Rating);
        recipeCreated.DateOfOrigin.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.DateOfOrigin);
        recipeCreated.HaveMadeItMyself.Should().Be(fakeRecipeOne.HaveMadeItMyself);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible in v2 but is in the v3 backlog: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2055